# Avoid deadlock in parallel transactions in pl/pgsql with nested insert

Tags: postgresql, transactions, plpgsql, vk

I have an pl/pgsql function whick receive posts from VK user's wall in json format and writes data into table.
This function is called in 40 threads, and deadlock may happen if identical posts from `copy_history` section (reposts) appear in parallel transactions.

I see so far only two solutions:

1. remove unique index and delete duplicate rows after unloading. But it can be very long in the case of a large table (~ 100 million and more)
2. insert `copy_history` posts into other table and merge this tables after unloading. I think this is not a very beautiful solution :)

```sql
create table vk_wall (
    id integer, from_id integer,
    owner_id integer, date integer,
    post_type text, post_text text,
    copy_history_id integer,
    copy_history_owner_id integer
);
create unique index on vk_wall (owner_id,id);

create or replace function write_vk_wall(response_arr jsonb) 
returns void as $$
    declare arg1 jsonb; declare arg2 jsonb;
    begin
-- response_arr is an json array of posts
    for arg1 in select(jsonb_array_elements(response_arr)) loop
        insert into vk_wall
            select 
            convert_to_int(arg1->>'id'),
            convert_to_int(arg1->>'from_id'),
            convert_to_int(arg1->>'owner_id'),
            convert_to_int(arg1->>'date'),
            arg1->>'post_type',
            arg1->>'text',
            convert_to_int(t.id),
            convert_to_int(t.owner_id)         
            from jsonb_to_recordset(arg1->'copy_history') as t(id text, owner_id text)
        on conflict do nothing;
-- 'copy_history' is a nested json object containing the original post.
        for arg2 in select(jsonb_array_elements(arg1->'copy_history')) loop
        insert into vk_wall
            select 
            convert_to_int(arg2->>'id'),
            convert_to_int(arg2->>'from_id'),
            convert_to_int(arg2->>'owner_id'),
            convert_to_int(arg2->>'date'),
            arg2->>'post_type',
            arg2->>'text',
            convert_to_int(arg2#>>'{copy_history,id}'),
            convert_to_int(arg2#>>'{copy_history,owner_id}')
        on conflict do nothing;
        end loop; end loop; 
    return; end; 
$$ language plpgsql;
```